# How to enable TLS1.2 for MariaDB?

Tags: mysql

I try to get MariaDB to work with TLS1.2. Out of the box and after enabling the following configuration

```
ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/ca.pem
ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key = /etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

it seems that the server is using TLS1.1 as I get the following error using JDBC connecting to the server:

```
The server selected protocol version TLS11 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]
```

As TLS1.1 is deprecated I want to enable TLS1.2.
After reading several docs how to specify which TLS protocol should be used - all of them stating that the following should do the trick

```
tls_version = TLSv1.2
```

However, after adding this property the server fails to start:

> 2021-11-19 18:16:51 0 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'tls_version=TLSv1.2'

Funny is - I cant find any reasonable information if I search for this error.

How can I enable TLS1.2 with MariaDB then?

Edit: I use Ubuntu 20.04 with latest mariadb-server package from Distro

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution. It seems that the package within Ubuntu isn't suitable to connect with newer TLS versions. After I found [this documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-deb-files/#adding-the-mariadb-apt-repository) from MariaDB itself, I was able to install the binaries from their repository which worked out of the box.